# Media Player Playlist Class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a playlist class for my media player I'm working on. I want to store the file name location and a display name for a list box. The class code i have is:

```
class Playlist
{
    private string filename;
    private string displayname;

    public Playlist(string strfilename, string strdisplayname)
    {
        this.filename = strfilename;
        this.displayname = strdisplayname;
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filename;
        }
        set
        {
            this.filename = value;
        }
    }
    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.displayname;
        }
        set
        {
            this.displayname = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the form i have two buttons. One to add a file and another to get the file name location of it.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Playlist playlistdata = new Playlist(@"c:\filenametest","displayname");

        lstMain.Items.Add(playlistdata.DisplayName);
    }
```

This one works fine. Now when i went to try to get info from the class from another button I'm having issues figuring out what to do. I want to try to do something like this but not sure how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Playlist playlistdata = lstMain.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show(playlistdata.FileName);
    }
```

Comment: Try `lstMain.SelectedItem as Playlist`.

Comment: What exactly does not work and how should it work? I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: For example lets say i have 5 songs in the playlist and in my listbox. I want to select one of the songs and be able to get the filename location of it. "Playlist playlistdata = lstMain.SelectedItem;" this line of code gives me a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Vicks_Music_Player_2.Classes.Playlist'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" error.

Comment: How does the playlist items get into the Listbox?  The Items collection is all Object, you need to convert/cast back when you get one.  There are alternatives depending on how the data got there

Comment: I'm going to add them to a listbox using this code "Playlist playlistdata = new Playlist(@"c:\filenametest","displayname");" and "lstMain.Items.Add(playlistdata);" This code worked in VB.Net as I'm just re making my program in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement the ToString() method from Playlist

```
class Playlist
{
...

  public string ToString()
  {
    return this.DisplayName;
  }
...
}
```

Instead of adding the DisplayName you can now add the Playlist object to the list:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Playlist playlistdata = new Playlist(@"c:\filenametest","displayname");

    lstMain.Items.Add(playlistdata);
}
```

Now you can access the data:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Playlist playlistdata = (Playlist)lstMain.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(playlistdata.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked great! I really appreciate the help.